# Does exists some external text viewer for AOD files?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

Does exists some external text viewer for read AOD source files of Axapta ?
I would like to backup it each X hour, then try to read the 'past' versions of source code. 
Thanks

Comment: sounds like you are trying to re-write source control, maybe you should be looking at turning source control on? I have some code for backing up classes/objects to XPO files if you want it? Also, XPO files are just simple text files, you can read them (to an extent) in any text file viewer/editor.

Comment: Mmm... yes source control isnt enabled. I didn't know it existed.

Comment: a bit of initial reading for you http://blogs.msdn.com/b/axsupport/archive/2011/05/31/working-with-version-control-in-ax.aspx

Comment: Maybe you make it an answer, it is more useful than mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying to re-write source control, maybe you should be looking at turning source control on? [see here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/axsupport/archive/2011/05/31/working-with-version-control-in-ax.aspx)

I have some code for backing up classes/objects to XPO files if you want it? [It is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306731/where-are-the-source-files-of-ax-stored/11308368#11308368)

Also, XPO files are just simple text files, you can read them (to an extent) in any text file viewer/editor

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no.

And I agree with Anthony.