# Dynamics AX 2009: Where is kept class, macro files?

Tags: axapta, x++

I want to get the source code of classes, macros, forms etc.

Where is it kept? On a local disk or on version control (I use MorphX VCS)?

And how can I get it?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/11306731/4509

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where are the source files of AX stored?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306731/where-are-the-source-files-of-ax-stored)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code of X++ isn't stored as text anywhere in AX 2009, it's stored in binary form in the application files.

If you go to your application folder you will find *.aod, *.ahd, *.ald, *.add, *.khd files for all of your layers, but those are in binary form.

If you want to see them as text the only way is to open them in the code editor in the AX client, or export them to an XPO file.

If you are using TFS as a source control client, each check-in will generate an xpo file on your local disk and check in that xpo in source control.